# Cloud Firestore await future within stream - join user to document using user id

Tags: flutter, join, google-cloud-firestore, stream, future

I am listening to a stream of documents and within each document lies a uid which I’d like to use to get the user profile associated with that document. Kinda like a join but in the case of firestore just fetching the user profile so I’d have the most up to date user profile associated with that document. Since getting the user profile would be a separate query that returns a future, how would I go about getting the profile while also getting my stream. The only working solution I have so far has to do with a nested future builder under multiple stream builders but I need a better solution. Below is my code.

```
Stream<List<Tab>> get sentTabs {
return _db
    .collection('tabs')
    .where('sender', isEqualTo: user.uid)
    .snapshots()
    .map((list) => list.docs.map((doc) {
          Tab tab = Tab.fromJson(doc.data(), doc.id);
          // i'd like to fetch the associated user profile here // tab.shownUser = await getUser(tab.payerUID!);
          return tab;
        }).toList());
```

}

Comment: so instead of `Stream.map` you need [Stream.asyncMap](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html) (or [Stream.asyncExpand](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/asyncExpand.html))?

Comment: Pretty much but those map methods aren’t available

Comment: [snapshots()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/snapshots.html) method returns a `Stream` so how come `Stream.asyncMap` is not available?

Comment: snapshots() returns a Stream but list.docs returns a list of query snapshots which is where I need to fetch the associated user profile, or do you think there's a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue several times and the most useful solution I found is exactly what you proposed: use `FutureBuilder` inside the `StreamBuilder`

```
Tab tab = Tab.fromJson(doc.data(), doc.id);
//Add a FutureBuilder
return FutureBuilder(
    future: getUser(tab.payerUID!),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      //your logic here
    }
return tab;
)
```

Later to make it more optimized I used a StreamProvider because I am using the same stream in multiple locations in my code.

Bottom line: There is no magic, you need to query the database twice.